# Django: Import data from uploaded excel file

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create an app to import thanks to an uploaded .csv file data to my database. This is where I've managed to arrive by myself: my file is uploaded without problems and I can pass the information from the file to the variable first_row and second row. My problem now is how I can save the information in the database. My views code:

VIEWS

```
@login_required
def file_upload(request):
    data = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        file_form = FileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        data_form = DatasetForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        raw_file= request.FILES
        if file_form.is_valid() or data_form.is_valid():       
            data = request.FILES['file_upload']             
            data = pd.read_csv(data, header=0, encoding="UTF-8")                   
            first_row = data.iloc[[0]]
            second_row = data.iloc[[1]] 
                            
            file_form.instance.user = request.user.profile    
            file_form.instance.filename = raw_file['file_upload'].name            
            file_form.save() 
            return redirect('upload_file')
        else:
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = FileForm()  
 
    context = {              
               'data': data,
               'second_row': second_row,
               'file_form': file_form,                             
               'message': message,         
               }
    return render(request, 'upload_file.html', context)
```

These are how my data and models looks:
DATA

```
        code  tot sd     
name_1  aa    3    1
name_2  bb    7    2
```

MODEL

```
class File(models.Model): 
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)   
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=250)   
    file_upload = models.FileField(upload_to=path)
    upload_date  = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)   

    def __str__(self):        
        return self.user.name + 'file'

class Dataset(models.Model):    
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file_uploaded = models.OneToOneField(File, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    name_user_A = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    code_user_A = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    total_user_A = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    sd_user_A = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)

    name_user_B = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    code_user_B = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    total_user_B = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    sd_user_B = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
```

FORMS

```
class FileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = File
        fields = '__all__'


class DatasetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Dataset
        fields = '__all__'
```

Basicaly I need to save the first row in the field for user_A and the second row for the user_B. Only the model File is compiled by the user, while Dataset should be filled automatically from the information in the file.  How can I do this? Thank you all!
PS(I had to do some change to make it shorter and more understandable, there could be some typo but it's acutally works)

Comment: You can just retrieve data and create an object based on that.

Answer (score 1):

If you import your Dataset model you can create a new object based on the data you've already got from the file.

for example:

```
#import your model
from . models import Dataset


@login_required
def file_upload(request):
    data = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        file_form = FileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        data_form = DatasetForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        raw_file= request.FILES
        if file_form.is_valid() or data_form.is_valid():       
            data = request.FILES['file_upload']             
            data = pd.read_csv(data, header=0, encoding="UTF-8")                   
            first_row = data.iloc[[0]]
            second_row = data.iloc[[1]] 

            # create new dataset object
            Dataset.objects.create(
                name_user_A=first_row,
                name_user_B=second_row,
                ...,
                ...)
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying your advice and I'm getting this `error = NOT NULL constraint failed: app_data.file_uploaded_id`. I think I should automatically link the data form to the file form? I've tried this `data_form.file_uploaded = request.file_uploaded.file` and I'm getting this error `'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'file_uploaded'`. Thank you again for the helps

Comment: How do you show user the values that didn't get imported due to DB Integrity errors?